# Determine incoming URL/HTTP_REFERER without getting spoofed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cookies, iframe

**Brief explanation:**

A User gets an iframe embed-link (ex: < iframe src="https://www.platform.com/HASH">)

1. Using HASH from URL, determine the User, check if the request is coming from one of User's domain and increase view.
2. View count logic: If a shopper(users customer, not mine) calls a users page, then increase view count and the same User's shopper can call the page as many times as he want for the next 30 min, without the view being increased.

Any tip how 1. and 2. can be implemented. Thanks for all your support.

Comment: @Dave I am not asking you to write code for me, I am just asking politely, what possibilities there are to implement the above mentioned scenario, nothing more.

Comment: Afraid that isn't how SO works. You need to show us your effort and we will try to help you. Please take a look at the links in my comment for further information.

Comment: I'm afraid that what you're asking is not possible. _User Agents_ and the _Http Referer_ header can always be spoofed by the client. From the server perspective, you cannot verify the validity of these values and must accept them at face value. Therefore, if you need to be absolutely sure, you'll need to use something like _OAuth 2.0_...

Comment: Sounds like the problem here is that you are rewarding views (which are pretty worthless, and [easily faked even without bots](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/click-farm)) and not conversions.

Comment: @Quentin not rewarding, charging customer per view.